# My program exited without running with return value 3221225620

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a C++ code that calculates a student's percentage grade.
This is a sample of what the output should look like

```
Enter student's first and last name: John Smith
Number of questions on the test: 40
Number of answers the student got correct: 31
John Smith 77.5%
```

Below is my own code. It allows me to enter the first line:
`Enter student's first and last name:`
but then it just exits and this is the feedback
`return value 3221225620`

Please, what am I doing wrong?

```cpp
// Lab 3 percentage.cpp
// This program will determine the percentage
// of answers a student got correct on a test.

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int numQuestions,
        numCorrect,
        studentName;
    double percentage;

    // Get student's test data
    cout << "Enter student's first and last name: ";
    cin >> studentName;

    cout << "Number of questions on the test: ";
    cin >> numQuestions;

    cout << "Number of answers the student got correct: ";
    cin >> numCorrect;

    // Compute and display the student's % correct
    percentage = (numCorrect / numQuestions) * 100;
    // WRITE A STATEMENT TO COMPUTE THE % AND ASSIGN THE RESULT TO percentage.

    cout << "The student: " << studentName << "has a test score of " << percentage << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think this is doing: `cin >> studentName;`.  Don't just tell me what you think it is doing.  _Read the code you wrote_ and see what it is doing.  It might help you learn C++ if you used a development environment (IDE) that helped you with things like showing you the types of expressions when you hover over them, showed you declarations when you hovered over a use of a variable, , etc. etc.

Comment: Potentially relevant: a return code of `3221225620 = 0xC0000094` on Windows seems to indicate a hardware division by zero exception.

Comment: `cin >> studentName;` -- The `studentName` is declared as an `int`.  Please go over your code again.  In addition, if your code doesn't work, the *last* place you want to go to is StackOverflow, not the first place.  The first thing you should do is go over your code, print out variables, etc. so that *you* can figure out where your program goes wrong.  Maybe you won't know *how* to fix the problem, but at the very least, you should know *where* the problem is occurring.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `numCorrect / numQuestions` will almost always return 0

Comment: Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Read the documentation of your compiler and of your debugger. See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Enter student's first and last name: ";
cin >> studentName;
```

studentName is an integer and you need to receive a string and above in your code you defined

```
string name;
```

so what you need to do is :

```
cin >> name;
```

but when you want to receive first name and last name, there is a space between them so instead of using cin, you need to use :

```
getline(cin, name);
```

and finally fix this :

```
cout << "The student: " << studentName << "has a test score of " << percentage << endl;
```

with :

```
cout << "The student: " << name << "has a test score of " << percentage << endl;
```